# Is there a Stack Exchange for A.I. Ethics and/or ethical usage?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation, stack-exchange

#### Objective

I was having a bit of trouble trying to figure which Stack Exchange branch to: 'find answers to' or 'pose a question' about Artificial Intelligence ethics.
[image: Why I am asking here]

#### Example Inquiries

With Microsoft's recent posting of combining their search engine `Bing` with a powerful A.I. such as `ChatGPT`, is data mining their users more acceptable now? Is net neutrality and anonymity going to be more frowned upon, then the stigma it seems to have already gained? Is it (going to be or) acceptable to loose privacy for gains from Artificial Intelligence with other companies services/softwares? Are there studies related to this topic of A.I. ethics? or does it fall under another category of study?

#### Considerations

I have considered the SE branches: Academia, Philosophy, & Artificial Intelligence. The search tags I've used are: `privacy`, `ethics`, `studies`, `case-studies`, `law`, `A.I.`, and the like.
I think philosophy might be the one to pose A.I. ethics questions, but would rather check in with users who have more experience on SE branches.

Comment: While looking at the tags might be helpful, the best is to look into the "help/on-topic" docs, i.e. for Artificial Intellingence checkout https://ai.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic, after that also take a look to the per-site metas to learn about the recent discussions related to the site scope.

Comment: @Rubén In taking a look at that earlier, my concern was debating whether my queries would be more ethic/philosophical based do to specified [Ethics 3](https://ai.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic#:~:text=Data%20Science-,Philosophy,-Stack%20Overflow). The image was just one example of my prior searches.

Comment: Could you remove brands names like Microsoft, Bing and ChatGPT from your question or they are so important that your question doesn't make sence without them ? Are you able to find related questions on one or more of the sites that you initiatially considered?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's no current SE site specifically for dealing with A.I. ethics and/or ethical usage. Among the 3 possible sites you mentioned, i.e., [Academia](https://academia.stackexchange.com/), [Philosophy](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/) and [Artificial Intelligence](https://ai.stackexchange.com/), I think the Academia site will likely be an appropriate choice only in fairly special cases such as if the question is specifically about how A.I. is being used in academia, what sort of A.I. ethics (or lack thereof) is being taught, etc. Nonetheless, I agree that the Philosophy site would generally be the best one regarding ethics (e.g., with your example queries), with the Artificial Intelligence site also being a good possibility, since you're asking specifically about A.I.

Note that, depending on what you're specifically you're asking, there are several other SE sites that might actually be better choices. Two that I believe are ones to consider in certain cases are [Law](https://law.stackexchange.com/) and [Information Security](https://security.stackexchange.com/).

Regardless of which site you're considering to post on, especially if you're not already relatively familiar with it, I agree with [Rubén's comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/386526/is-there-a-stack-exchange-for-a-i-ethics-and-or-ethical-usage#comment1288852_386526) that you should do some research first, e.g., read what the Help Center says is on-topic, check the site's meta posts, find and read several posts that have whatever tag(s) you think are appropriate to use, etc.

Comment: This was very helpful in helping me search correctly and after more research, I'll be able to pose better questions, thank you & @Rubén. I found related topics: [SE Law](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/64338/what-is-defined-as-low-or-minimal-risk-artificial-intelligence-and-which-obliga), [SE Information Security](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/237945/are-there-any-projects-papers-on-approaching-exploit-development-with-ai-automat), which took toward better search queries, and finding [US Gov AI Policy Bill](https://www.whitehouse.gov/ostp/ai-bill-of-rights/)